# Does "pensive" happen to have a meaning related to suspense?

Tags: meaning

There is a thriller movie named "Pensive".

"pensive" means engaged in, involving, or reflecting deep or serious thought. The movie is full of explicit killing, and not at all thought provoking.

What does "pensive" mean as the name of a thriller movie? Does it happen to have a meaning related to suspense?

"suspensive" means causing suspense, so is it more appropriate than "pensive"?

Comment: Pensive means what you say.  Why the director (or marketing person) thought it was suitable for the name of a slasher movie is anybody's guess.  Unless there is an interview with the director in which they explain this you won't get an answer.

Comment: It's a translation of  Lithuanian: Rūpintojėlis  *The Pensive Christ (Lithuanian: Rūpintojėlis) is a subject in Christian iconography depicting a contemplating Jesus, sitting with his head supported by his hand.*  Do wooden statues like this play a part in the movie?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not matter of learning English.  The name of a movie doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: You could ask on Movies and TV SE why it has that title.

Answer (score 1):

"Pensive" probably relates to the Christ attitude in the statues destroyed by classmates at the beginning of the movie.

This attitude can recall [the thinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thinker) by Auguste Rodin.

Comment: I think you mean "This attitude can remind a viewer of the Thinker by Rodin" or "This attitude can recall The Thinker by Rodin." "Remind" is transitive and takes as an object the person who is remembering, not the thing being remembered; "recall" or "remember" take as an object the thing being remembered ("He remembered the holiday"). And "The Thinker of Rodin" means the statue owned by Rodin not the statue created by Rodin; "Rodin's The Thinker" would also be common.

Comment: @StuartF: I updated my answer according to your remarks. I am quite surprised by [ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thinker+of+rodin%2Cthinker+by+rodin%2CRodin%27s+The+Thinker&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) about The Thinker, particularly [between 1918 and 1940](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thinker+of+rodin%2Cthinker+by+rodin%2CRodin%27s+The+Thinker&year_start=1918&year_end=1940&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).